# Log robocopy output that is initiated via runas

Tags: logging, robocopy

I have the following command I issue:

```
runas /savecred /user:domain\user "robocopy C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation \\share\drive\Backups\Apache /MIR /XD C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.4\donotcopy\"
```

This works fine, but I also want to log the output from the initiated robocopy window. When I try adding >> C:\apache-backup.log to the end of the above command, i just get an empty log file. When I try adding it inside the quotes quotes after the directory to ignore, it does create the log file at all. Any suggestions on what I could try.

Answer (score 0):

By adding cmd.exe into the command it resolved my issue with logging.

```
runas /savecred /user:domain\user "cmd.exe robocopy C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation \\share\drive\Backups\Apache /MIR /XD C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.4\donotcopy\ >> ApacheBackup.log"
```